# How can I use a property on my Job instead of JobDataMap dictionary in Quartz.NET?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

I am working on a Windows service which needs to schedule tasks whenever one of it's web services is called. This could happen hundreds of times per second in a worst case scenario. The task needs to wait a period of time, typically a minute or two, then call a method passing a parameter.

We tried to build our own scheduler class to do this:

```
public void ScheduleTask<T>(TimeSpan delay, Action<T> task, T arg)
{
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
    threadPool.ExecuteAsync(task, arg);
}
```

But we figured this wouldn't be appropriate because we could theoretically end up with  hundreds of Thread Pool threads all waiting. I am under the impression that there is a finite number of Thread Pool threads available and that this could potentially lock up the system.

I then turned to Quartz.NET and read on [their features page](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/features.html) that:

> Job class instances can be instantiated by Quartz.NET, or by your application's framework.

and on [page 3 of their tutorial](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_3.html) that the Scheduler creates instances of your Job class (not you) and as such:

> it does not make sense to have data-members defined on the job class as their values would be 'cleared' every time the job executes.

Feel free to yell at me, but **how do I get a reference to my Job class instance before it executes so I can set a property on it?**

- The property is doing the job of a
  parameter so i have no interest in it
  after the Job has executed.
- I also want to minimise the number of
  objects it takes to acheive this to
  keep my code *neat* and *simple*.
- Finally, I seriously dislike using
  Dictionaries so would prefer to avoid the JobDataMap object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what your use case is and why you would need to set a property on the job, but to answer your question: to get access to your job before it executes you need to create a job listener (implement IJobListener). The job listener gets called just before the job gets executed, so you could set a property at that point.

Some links:
[The documentation on job listeners](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_7.html)

I wrote a blog post detailing the creation of listeners, [here](http://jvilalta.blogspot.com/2010/11/creating-quartznet-joblistener.html).